# Access Violation при загрузке dll

Tags: c#, access, dll, библиотеки, загрузка

В общем гружу dll библиотеку которую сделал сам, во время загрузки вылазит Error :

> Программа "[21524] hello.vshost.exe" завершилась с кодом -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Как вы думаете в чём может быть проблема?
Гружу вот так :

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(fname);
```

Comment: Библиотека нативная или управляемая?

Comment: А как отличить?

Comment: На чем написана?

Comment: На C# конечно же

Comment: Управляемая значит. Грузите в проект через References, и работайте с ней нормально. Или нужна конкретно подгрузка через рефлексию\отражение (System.Reflection)?

Comment: Ну я хотел бы чтобы программа грузила все dll из папки "plugin" и количество dll может быть разным, у них будет один и тот же интерфейс

Comment: А в библиотеке есть P/Invoke?

Comment: На вскидку три варианта: а) Попробуйте запустить студию от имени Администратор, и отлаживать. б) Попробуйте все же добавить dll в References и вызвать метод нормально. в) Отключить\удалить все антивирусы (иногда отключение не помогает, аверы молча блокируют, помогает только удаление).

Comment: @VladD всмысле invoke

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread342135.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, проблему решил, я даже не думал что из-за такой ерунды будут такие проблемы ...

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(fname);
```

Comment: Это не похоже на корректное решение. Вы каким-то образом «не цепляете» ошибку, но ошибка всё ещё на месте

Comment: @VladD я понимаю что это кастыль, зато он рабочий :D